# Display data in a Boostrap table from Posgres DB (Angular 11 + C# + PosgreSQL webstack)

Tags: c#, angular, postgresql, npgsql

Hello and thank you for looking at my question in advance. I'm still a beginner and what I'm trying to do is to display data to a Bootstrap Table from PostgreSQL DB via API get and I can't seem to get it to work. But whenever I use Postman/JSON Viewer in the browser either with NPGSQL or MS SQL as my DB it works just fine.

Thank you so much :)

**my working Web stack**

- **front-end:** Angular 11 w/ bootstrap table
- **back-end:** C# (.net Core 5)
- **DB:** MS SQL

**snapshots**
[image][image]

**my WIP Web stack**

- **front-end:** Angular 11 w/ bootstrap table
- **back-end:** C# (.net Core 5)
- **DB:** PostgreSQL (using NPGSQL NOT EF CORE)

**snapshot**
[image]
[image]

**DepartmentController.cs**

```
// default imports

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// user imports 
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using webAPIv3.models; // import Employee.cs and Department.cs models 
using Npgsql; //-----> added this to try out PostgreSQL


namespace webAPIv3.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DepartmentController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public DepartmentController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        //
        //
        //      Npgsql CONNECTION TRIAL HERE!!!!
        //      WORKING FINE NOW!!
        //
        //
         private void npgConnDriver(string query, DataTable table) {
            try
            {
                string npgSqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppCon");
                NpgsqlDataReader myReader;
                using (NpgsqlConnection myCon = new NpgsqlConnection(npgSqlDataSource)) {
                    myCon.Open();
                    using (NpgsqlCommand myCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, myCon)) {
                        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        table.Load(myReader);
                        myReader.Close();
                        myCon.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("\nMessage ---\n{0}", ex.Message);
               Console.WriteLine("\nHelpLink ---\n{0}", ex.HelpLink);
               Console.WriteLine("\nSource ---\n{0}", ex.Source);
               Console.WriteLine("\nStackTrace ---\n{0}", ex.StackTrace);
               Console.WriteLine("\nTargetSite ---\n{0}", ex.TargetSite);
            }
        }

        //
        //                  MS SQL IMPLEMENTATION
        //
        // private void connDriver(string query, DataTable table)
        // {
        //     try
        //     {
        //         string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeAppCon");
        //         SqlDataReader myReader;
        //         using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
        //         {
        //             myCon.Open();
        //             using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
        //             {
        //                 myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        //                 table.Load(myReader);
        //                 myReader.Close();
        //                 myCon.Close();
        //             }
        //         }
        //     }
        //     catch (Exception ex)
        //     {
        //         Console.WriteLine("\nMessage ---\n{0}", ex.Message);
        //         Console.WriteLine("\nHelpLink ---\n{0}", ex.HelpLink);
        //         Console.WriteLine("\nSource ---\n{0}", ex.Source);
        //         Console.WriteLine("\nStackTrace ---\n{0}", ex.StackTrace);
        //         Console.WriteLine("\nTargetSite ---\n{0}", ex.TargetSite);
        //     }
        // }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            // POSTGRESQL
            string query = @"select DepartmentId, DepartmentName from department";

            // MS SQL

            // string query = @"select DepartmentId, DepartmentName from dbo.department";
            
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            //  POSTGRESQL
             npgConnDriver(query, table);

            // FOR MS SQL
            // connDriver(query, table);
            return new JsonResult(table);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Post(Department dep)
        {

            // POSTGRESQL
             //
            string query =@"
                    insert into department (departmentname) values ('" + dep.DepartmentName + @"')
                 ";
            // MS SQL
            //
            // string query = @"
            //     insert into dbo.department (departmentname) values ('" + dep.DepartmentName + @"')";

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            npgConnDriver(query, table);    //  POSTGRESQL

            // connDriver(query, table);     // FOR MS SQL

            return new JsonResult("Added Successfully");
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public JsonResult Put(Department dep)
        {
            // POSTGRESQL
            //
            string query =
                @"
                    update Department set DepartmentName = '" + dep.DepartmentName + @"'
                    where DepartmentId = '" + dep.DepartmentId + @"'    ";
            // MS SQL
            //
            // string query =
            //    @"
            //    update dbo.Department set DepartmentName = '" + dep.DepartmentName + @"'
            //    where DepartmentId = '" + dep.DepartmentId + @"'
            //    ";

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            npgConnDriver(query, table);    //POSTGRESQL

            // connDriver(query, table);     // FOR MS SQL
            return new JsonResult("Updated Successfully");
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        //need to change the argument from Department dep to an int id since it is much better if the identifier to find is the Department Id
        public JsonResult Delete(int id){
            //  POSTGRESQL
            //
            string query =
                @"
                    Delete from Department
                    where DepartmentId = '" + id + @"'
                ";
            //  MS SQL
            //
            // string query =
            //     @"
            //     Delete from dbo.Department
            //     where DepartmentId = '" + id + @"'
            //    ";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            npgConnDriver(query, table);    //  POSTGRESQL
            // connDriver(query, table);     // FOR MS SQL
            return new JsonResult("Deleted Successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  // this will be different from what i planned to do. need to follow microsoft sql tutorial first
  "ConnectionStrings": {
   "EmployeeAppCon": "Host=localhost;Database=AaronDB;Port=*myPortNumber*;Username=postgres;Password=*myPassword*;Pooling=true;"
  },

  // "ConnectionStrings": {
  //   "EmployeeAppCon": "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=EmployeeDB; Integrated Security=true"
  // },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**show-dept.component.html**

```
<!-- Angular Material Dialog -->
<button mat-raised-button (click)="addDepartment()">Add Department</button>



<!--  table from bootstrap -->

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>DepartmentId</th>
      <th>DepartmentName</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr  *ngFor="let dataItem of DepartmentList">
      <td>{{ dataItem.DepartmentId }}</td>
      <td>{{ dataItem.DepartmentName }}</td>
      <td>
        <!-- edit button -->
        <button
          mat-icon-button
          color="accent"
          aria-label="example icon with a edit icon"
          (click)="editDepartment(dataItem)"
          class="material-icons"
        >
          <mat-icon> edit </mat-icon>
        </button>
        <!-- delete button -->
        <button
          mat-icon-button
          color="warn"
          class="material-icons"
          aria-label="example icon with a delete icon"
          type="button"
          (click)="deleteDepartment()"
        >
          <mat-icon> delete </mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**show-dept.component.ts**

```
// 1) import the shared service to use the written API methods
import { SharedService } from './../../shared.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialDesignModule } from './../../material-design/material-design.module';
import { AddEditDeptComponent } from './../add-edit-dept/add-edit-dept.component';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material/dialog';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-dept',
  templateUrl: './show-dept.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-dept.component.css']
})
export class ShowDeptComponent implements OnInit {

  // 2) instantiate the shared service in the constructor
  constructor(private service: SharedService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  // 3) assign an empty array for now
  DepartmentList: any = [];

  // variables for the dialog
  modalTitle: string;
  activateAddEditComp: boolean = false;
  dep: any;
  designator: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // 5) also need to call refresh method to the ng init as this is the first executed code on show-dept-component.ts
    this.refreshDepList();
  }

  // 4) write a method to refresh the department list from the API method
  // note:
  // This method is using asynchronous operation. RESEARCH MORE ABOUT THIS
  // the subscribe method makes sure to wait until the response is received from API call and
  // then only assigns a value to the department list variable

  refreshDepList() {
    this.service.getDepList().subscribe(data => {
      this.DepartmentList = data;
    });
  }


  // method adding department to the dialog box
  addDepartment() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    // this dialog configuration are not in use anymore since im using a MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS in app.module.ts <-----------DOES NOT WORK !!!!
    // dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    // dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    // dialogConfig.hasBackdrop = true;
    // dialogConfig.position = {
    //   top: '0', right: '0',
    // };
    // dialogConfig.minHeight = '250px';
    // dialogConfig.minWidth = '250px';
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.hasBackdrop = true;
    dialogConfig.data = {
      dep : {
        DepartmentId: 0,
        DepartmentName: ''
      },
      modalTitle: 'Add Department',
      activateAddEditComp: true,
      designator: 'my add department works'
    };

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddEditDeptComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('dialog result: ${result}');
    });
  }

  editDepartment(item){
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.hasBackdrop = true;

    dialogConfig.data = {
      dep : item,
      modalTitle: 'Edit Department',
      activateAddEditComp: true,
      designator: 'my edit department works'
    };

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddEditDeptComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('dialog result: ${result}');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: How exactly does your code "not work"? Please post a full exception with stack trace.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide any exceptions but I think I got the solution now. my column name from MS SQL DB( DepartmentId, DepartmentName) is different from PostgreSQL(departmentid, departmentname). Though in theory RDBMS like these are NOT case sensitive unless quoted. That is not the case in Angular. 

So my problem lies in show-dept.component.html where 
<td>{{ dataItem.DepartmentId }}</td>
<td>{{ dataItem.DepartmentName }}</td>

should be 

<td>{{ dataItem.departmentid }}</td>
<td>{{ dataItem.departmentname }}</td>

thank you for looking into my question and GLHV